# Swift: Storing states in CoreData with enums

Tags: core-data, swift

I want to store an enum state for a managed object within CoreData

```
enum ObjStatus: Int16 {
    case State1 = 0
    case State2 = 1
    case State3 = 3
}

class StateFullManagedObject: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var state: Int16
}
```

The last step would be converting the state var of StateFullManagedObject to ObjStatus for direct comparison, which isn't working for me. For example, I can't use the == operator between and Int16 and the Int16 enum. The compile time error I get is

> Int16 is not convertible to 'MirrorDisposition'

.  See the conditional below:

```
var obj: StateFullManagedObject = // get the object

if (obj.state == ObjStatus.State1) { // Int16 is not convertible to 'MirrorDisposition'

}
```

How can I compare/assign between an Int16 and an enum?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can extract raw `Int16` value with `.rawValue` property of `ObjStatus`.

```
// compare
obj.state == ObjStatus.State1.rawValue

// store
obj.state = ObjStatus.State1.rawValue
```

But you might want to implement `stateEnum` accessor for it:

```
class StateFullManagedObject: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var state: Int16
    var stateEnum:ObjStatus {                    //  ↓ If self.state is invalid.
        get { return ObjStatus(rawValue: self.state) ?? .State1 }
        set { self.state = newValue.rawValue }
    }
}

// compare
obj.stateEnum == .State1

// store
obj.stateEnum = .State1

// switch
switch obj.stateEnum {
case .State1:
    //...
case .State2:
    //...
case .State3:
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yep this is pretty much what I do. I suffix the core data attribute with "Raw", and then have a computed property with the correct name that deals with the translation from the enum to the raw int.

Comment: This is very clean and beautiful swift solution! Thank you!!

Comment: You should **definitely** check the other answer for an actually _clean_ solution.

Comment: but I want to work with associated value in enum how can I do that in core data

Answer (score 108):

You can declare your enum as @objc. Then it all automagically works. Here's a snippet from a project I'm working on.

```
// Defined with @objc to allow it to be used with @NSManaged.
@objc enum AgeType: Int32
{
    case Age                = 0
    case LifeExpectancy     = 1
}

/// The age type, either Age or LifeExpectancy.
@NSManaged var ageType: AgeType
```

In the Core Data model, ageType is set to type Integer 32.

Comment: This is a much cleaner implementation.  Thanks!

Comment: Definitely the best solution. No need for private duplicating fields, transformers, etc.

Comment: I don't think it wokrs in the latest swift 2 - I get this error: Property cannot be marked @NSManaged because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

Comment: @MobileBloke I'm using the latest Xcode 7.2 beta 3 (7C62). This solution is still valid. What type are you trying to use in your enum?

Comment: @MobileBloke Is the property declared as optional?

Comment: I get the compiler error: "Enum case 'Age' not found in type NSNumber".

Comment: Wouldn't `@NSManaged var ageType: AgeType` be overwritten if you recreate the NSManagedObject subclass? Or do you override the type of `ageType` somewhere else, not in the `xxx+CoreDataProperties.swift` file?

Comment: @Arjan, I don't user Xcode's source code creation functions if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: If you want your property to be declared optional, as @Joony has mentioned, this solution will not work. You get "type cannot be represented in Objective-C". I don't have a solution for that scenario.

Comment: this solution works in Xcode 8/Swift 3/iOS 10, I just had to make the enum `public`.

Comment: int based ordinals for enums are a very bad idea, is there a way to do this with enemies defined as strings?

Comment: `@objc enum` works, but a disadvantage is that you won’t get a good `description` for free.

Comment: This does not work if you let xcode generate your properties from the model

Answer (score 16):

**Xcode 12.5 Swift 5**

I am storing the values of multiple `Enums` in `CoreData` with `CloudKit` Database.

There are quite a few precise steps required to get this working correctly.  I have set out here what I have learned works well.

**Step 1: Define your Enum:**

Mark it `@objc`, `public` and `Int16`

```
@objc
public enum SomeState: Int16 {
    case stateA
    case stateB
    case stateC
}
```

**Step 2: In your xcdatamodeld create an attribute where the Enum value will be stored**

The type should be `Integer 16`

[image]

**Step 3: In the Data Model Inspector uncheck Optional, and set a default value of 0**

This equates to the first index of the `Enum`.

[image]

**Step 4: In the Data Model Inspector for the parent Entity, change Class Codegen to Manual/None**

[image]

**Step 5: Create NSManaged Subclass**

Click on the Entity name, then from the menu bar select ***Editor > Create NSManagedObject*** Subclass.   Make sure that the Target is set to your main project.  This will create two new files in the project navigator.

***MyObject+CoreDataClass.swift***

***MyObject+CoreDataProperties.swift***

**Step 6: In the MyObject+CoreDataProperties.swift file change the attribute type from Int16 to your Enum type**

```
extension MyObject {

    @NSManaged public var state: SomeState

}
```

---

**USAGE:**

**Setting/updating the value:**

```
myObject.state = .stateA
```

**NSPredicate to search for enum value:**

```
NSPredicate(format: "state = %i", SomeState.stateA.rawValue)
```

Comment: Hello! Could we use the same solution with Category/Extension Codegen? Thanks. I tried to do it but got some errors

Comment: why should I mark the enum with `public` ? can't I remove it and keep the enum `internal` ?

Comment: Xcode 14.3.1 does not allow the marking of enum as public. The error: "Property cannot be declared public because its type uses an internal type".

Comment: So, wander if it still can be used in Core Data iCloud?