# Using enum as property of Realm model

Tags: ios, enums, realm

Is it possible to use an Enum as a property for my model? I currently have a class like this:

```
class Checkin: RLMObject {
  dynamic var id: Int = 0
  dynamic var kind: String = "checked_in"
  var kindEnum: Kind = .CheckedIn {
    willSet { self.kind = newValue.rawValue }
  }

  enum Kind: String {
    case CheckedIn = "checked_in"
    case EnRoute = "en_route"
    case DroppedOff = "dropped_off"
  }
  ....
}
```

It works okay, but I'd like to be able to have the `kind` property be the Enum and have Realm automatically call `.rawValue` on the property when it is saving an object to the store. Is this possible in Realm or is there a feature request already out there for it?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You should override your `kindEnum`'s setter and getter for this case:

```
enum Kind: String {
  case CheckedIn
  case EnRoute
  case DroppedOff
}

class Checkin: Object {
  @objc dynamic var id = 0
  var kind = Kind.CheckedIn.rawValue
  var kindEnum: Kind {
    get {
      return Kind(rawValue: kind)!
    }
    set {
      kind = newValue.rawValue
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Will be great if you could add this sample to your official examples.

Comment: This is not great. Why can't you do this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900302/swift-storing-states-in-coredata-with-enums (the Martin Krenek answer)?

Comment: You can use `@objc` enums directly with Realm too, but that won't work for Swift enums with `String` associated values.

Comment: In the absence of "official" support from Realm (if it's even possible), this is very useful. Thank you.

Comment: You could set kind variable as private, so you could only change its value with kindEnum.

Comment: just a suggestion: as I use the enum more than raw value in my code, I named them `kindRaw` and `kind`

Comment: Looks really awful

Answer (score 53):

I've refined this model a little further.

```
enum Thing: String {
    case Thing1
    case Thing2
    case Thing3
}
```

then in my Realm class object:

```
class myClass : Object {
    private dynamic var privateThing = Thing.Thing1.rawValue
    var thing: Thing {
        get { return Thing(rawValue: privateThing)! }
        set { privateThing = newValue.rawValue }
    }
}
```

This allows us to write

```
myClassInstance.thing = .Thing1
```

(storing "Thing1" into privateThing), but prevents typing of

```
myClassInstance.privateThing = "Thing4"
```

which is not a valid value so preserving data integrity.

Comment: Update: I've edited my original code because the the = "Thing1" etc. is redundant as Swift uses a String literal equivalent of the case for its rawValue, which is even better and we can use the rawValue to set the default which is more reliable and cleaner.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for this addition, I really like this answer. +1

Answer (score 40):

Realm 10.0.0 introduces [`PersistableEnum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/swift/examples/define-a-realm-object-model/#declare-enum-properties) Protocol that makes it easy to persist enum values without any third-party extensions.

```
enum TaskStatusEnum: String, PersistableEnum {
    case notStarted
    case inProgress
    case complete
}
// To use the enum:
class Task: Object {
    // Required enum property
    @Persisted var status = TaskStatusEnum.notStarted 
    // Optional enum property
    @Persisted var optionalTaskStatusEnumProperty: TaskStatusEnum? 
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer in 2022.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2022!!!

Comment: This is the real right answer!

Answer (score 20):

Since Realm support Objective-C enums and they are representable by `Int` you can use this:

```
class Checkin: Object {
  dynamic var id: Int = 0
  dynamic var kind: Kind = .checkedIn

  @objc enum Kind: Int {
    case checkedIn
    case enRoute
    case droppedOff
  }
  ....
}
```

If you need to parse to/from `String` you can use a custom initializer for `Kind` and an `toString` function.

There is a discussion about this in [GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/921)

This works with Swift `3.0` and Realm `2.0.2`

Comment: Nice solution if you have an `Int` enum, but it don't see how it can work with a `String` instead. `Kind` is converted to an Objective-C enum which doesn't support custom initializers or stored properties.. ?

Comment: Indeed, I haven't found a solution that work with any type but `Int`

Comment: Thank you for this information. 
I changed my enum to conform to an int. 
If you need a string value you can make your own computed property in the enum and return the proper value for the different cases.

Comment: Note that any migrations you do involving Int enums will need to assign the raw value: obj["propertyName"] = Kind.checkedIn.rawValue

Answer (score 13):

[Diogo T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634185/diogo-t)'s solution worked before recent updates of RealmSwift. Eventually we now have to conform to `RealmEnum` protocol to be able to be a managed property of Realm `Object`.

```
@objc enum MyEnum: Int, RealmEnum {
    ...
}
```

Or add below in some place:

```
extension MyEnum: RealmEnum { }
```

[RealmSwift documentation for it](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Protocols.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A4EnumP)

Answer (score 8):

### *Clean & Easy solution*

From *Realm* version `>= 10.10.0` you [can do this](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/swift/examples/define-a-realm-object-model/#declare-enum-properties):

```swift
// Define the enum
enum StatusEnum: String, PersistableEnum {
    case notStarted
    case inProgress
    case complete
}

// To use the enum:
class Task: Object {
    @Persisted var status = StatusEnum.notStarted 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with `RealmEnum` and `RealmOptional`

```
@objc enum MyEnum: Int, RealmEnum {
    case first
    case second
}

final class MyEntry: Object {
    //It should be let
    let someVariable = RealmOptional<CRUD>()
}

//using
myEntry.someVariable.value = MyEnum.first
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution to avoid the force un-wrap
get { return Thing(rawValue: privateThing)! }

```
enum Kind: String, CaseIterable {
      case CheckedIn
      case EnRoute
      case DroppedOff
    }

    @objc dynamic var kindRaw = Kind.CheckedIn.rawValue
    var kind: Kind {
        get {
            for kind in Kind.allCases where kindRaw == kind.rawValue {
                return kind
            }
            return .CheckedIn //default
        }
        set {
            kindRaw = newValue.rawValue
        }
    }
```