# 'dynamic' property must also be '@objc' error is happened for an Enum variable even if 'dynamic' is already added

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using RealmSwift in Xcode 10.2 and Swift4.2.

I made following code.

```swift
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

enum MyEnum {
    case enum1
    case enum2
    case enum3
}

class MyClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    @objc dynamic var myEnum: MyEnum?
}
```

Following error has been occurred when I build.

`'dynamic' property 'myEnum' must also be '@objc'`

As you can see, `@objc` is already added for `myEnum` variable, so I'm confused.
This error is occurred only for Enum variable.

Would you give me any solutions or advices ?

Comment: Only enums with `Int`(or other integer) raw value type can be represented in `Objective C` and marked with `@objc`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using enum as property of Realm model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123245/using-enum-as-property-of-realm-model)