# Using Enums in Realm Swift

Tags: swift, enums, realm

There is a few old thread that discuss the usage of Enums in Realm, and I adopted one them which works fine but I want to make sure that that is still the recommended way of doing it.

Is the following code the current-recommended way to use Enums with Realm?

**Realm Object**

```
enum SeatPreference: String {
    case Window
    case Middle
    case Aisle
}

class Ticket:Object{
    @objc private dynamic var preference = SeatPreference.Window.rawValue

    var seatPreference: SeatPreference {
        get { return SeatPreference(rawValue: preference)! }
        set { preference = newValue.rawValue }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
ticket.seatPreference = .Middle
```

Again, everything works fine, I just want someone to confirm that there is still not a better way of doing it.

Comment: Do you care how enum value is stored inside of `Realm` "table"? If you don't, you may just use `Int` based `enums` directly without proxy type conversion.

Comment: @user28434 No, not really. Would you mind showing me an example of what you are talking about? Also, do you see any benefit by storing them as `Int`s.

Comment: Just change `: String` to `: Int` add `@objc` to the type, mark `seatPreference` with `dynamic` and remove `getter`/`setter`. It is done. And benefit is native support, and an `Int` consumes less space that a `String`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using enum as property of Realm model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123245/using-enum-as-property-of-realm-model)

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks.