# How to use enums in RealmSwift now with the 4.0 update?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, realm

We used to be able to use enums in Realm Swift through getters and setters (see great solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123245/using-enum-as-property-of-realm-model)), but the latest update now requires us to conform to the RealmEnum protocol (link [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Protocols.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A4EnumP)). Being a beginner programmer, I unfortunately don't understand how to do this. Copying their code pops up a multitude of errors in XCode.

```
@objc enum class MyEnum: Int, RealmEnum { //says inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Int'
    case thing1 = 1 //says enum case is not allowed outside of an enum
    case thing2 = 2
    case thing3 = 3
}

class MyModel: Object {
   @objc dynamic enumProperty = MyEnum.thing1 //says expected 'var' keyword in property declaration
   let optionalEnumProperty = RealmOptional<MyEnum>() //says 'MyEnum is ambiguous for type lookup
}
```

How can I get enums working again in Realm Swift using the RealmEnum protocol?

Comment: I think that's just a typo in the documentation, `enum class` doesn't make sense, it should just be `@objc enum MyEnum: Int, RealmEnum {`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Dan, I figured it out. Two typos in the Realm documentation (I'll contact them to try to get them to fix it.) Corrected code below:

```
@objc enum MyEnum: Int, RealmEnum { //deleted the word class
    case thing1 = 1 
    case thing2 = 2
    case thing3 = 3
}

class MyModel: Object {
   @objc dynamic var enumProperty = MyEnum.thing1 //added the word var
   let optionalEnumProperty = RealmOptional<MyEnum>() 
}
```