# Set enum value to core data object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, enums

I have a core data object:

```
@objc enum ProductType:Int32 {
    case One
    case Two
}

class Product: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var productType:ProductType
}
```

I read about this here: [Swift: Storing states in CoreData with enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900302/swift-storing-states-in-coredata-with-enums)

Then i want to create object:

```
product = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Product", inManagedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext) as! Product

product.setValue(ProductType.One, forKey: "productType")
```

But compiler says:

> Cannot convert value of type '' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

And I doubt that this is right solution for work with enums...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to set properties via `setValue(: forKey:)`, the value has to be conformed to AnyObject; therefore, you can change enum to `NSNumber`, ex. `NSNumber(int: ProductType.Two.rawValue)`

If you would like to set properties via `enum ProductType` directly, to implement custom setter and getter can have the feature. Please take the following `Product` class for a reference:

```
class Product: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var productType: NSNumber?

    // For Option 3 by adding a ProductType property
    var type: ProductType {
        get {
            return ProductType(rawValue: self.productType!.intValue)!
        }
        set {
            self.productType = NSNumber(int:newValue.rawValue)
        }
    }
}

let product = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Product", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Product
// Option 1: Set productType via setValue(:forKey:)
product.setValue(NSNumber(int: ProductType.Two.rawValue), forKey: "productType")
// Option 2: Set productType directly
product.productType = NSNumber(int: ProductType.Two.rawValue)
// Option 3: set productType via an extra ProductType property
product.type = ProductType.Two
```